# Is there a way to sigaction() to a signal handler with multiple parameters?

Tags: c, parameters, handler, signals

I am using sigaction() to perform an action every time SIGINT is received. All tutorials I have seen use this prototype as a signal handler

```
void sig_handler(int sig);
```

Is there a way somehow to make this to take more parameters so it suits my needs? So for example

```
void sig_handler(char* surname, int age);
```

This is my code:

```
void sig_handler(int sig) {
    printf("SIGINT(%d) received\n", sig);
}

int main( ){
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler=sig_handler;

    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);

    while(1){};
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but you could set a global variable that tells your `sig_handler()` what to do.

```
int ACTION = 0;

void sig_handler(int sig) {
    if (sig == SIGINT) {
        switch (ACTION) {
          case 0: other_function(char* surname, int age);
          break;
        // more cases
        default:
          ;
        }
    } else if ( ....  // more signals
    }
}

int main( ){
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler=sig_handler;

    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);

    while(1){};
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Thought of it just before you answered but you get my vote still :D

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with signals. How would these parameters be supplied and delivered? A signal is just a predefined numeric code that causes the process to execute the handler asynchronously, by interrupting the main flow.

You can, however, use a Unix socket, a pipe, or a fifo file for this.